# Microsoft R rxDataStep - RowSelection

Tags: r, microsoft-r

I am new to Microsoft Revr. I am facing a small problem in the below code

```
FILTER<-"TRANS > 0"                                                  
max_rows_cols <- 100000000000000000000 

data1 <- rxDataStep(inData = data1,transformObjects=list(Filter=FILTER),
rowSelection =**noquote(Filter)** ,overwrite = TRUE,maxRowsByCols=max_rows_cols)
```

I get the value of FILTER at run time.

Is Something wrong with the row selection value?

Looking forward to help on this?

Answer (score 2):

The `rowSelection` argument should be an *expression* giving the rows to keep. You need to parse (but not evaluate) your filter text:

```
filterExpr <- parse(text=FILTER)
df <- rxDataStep(data1, rowSelection=filterExpr, maxRowsByCols=NULL)
```

Note that if you want to turn off the dataset size check, set `maxRowsByCols=NULL`.

Comment: If it worked, consider upvoting it and/or accepting the answer so others can find it later.

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation.Hence not displayed.@Hong Ooi

Answer (score 0):

We can use `eval(parse`

```
library(RevoScaleR)
rxDataStep(inData = data1, transformObjects=list(Filter=FILTER),
                  rowSelection = eval(parse(text=Filter)))
#  Rows Read: 5, Total Rows Processed: 5, Total Chunk Time: 0.003 seconds 
#  Col1 TRANS
#1    3     1
#2    4     3
#3    5     2
```

#### data

```
data1 <- data.frame(Col1 = 1:5, TRANS = c(-5, -4, 1, 3, 2))
FILTER<-"TRANS > 0"
```